# VB.NET Regex Match 5 and 10 char Zip Code in 1 Group

Tags: regex, vb.net, regex-group

I'm using this code

```
(\d{5})([\-]\d{4})?\s*
```

Which matches my Zip Code

```
12345-1234
```

in 2 groups

```
1. 12345
2. -1234
```

I need it to match both 12345 (5 char zip) and 12345-1234 (10 char zip) in 1 single group. Is that possible?

EDIT:

```
(\d{5}-\d{4}|\d{5})
```

(Thanks to vcsjones) satisfies the original question.

However it doesn't retrieve only 12345 in case of a malformed Zip (eg. 12345-123)

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give this one a try:

```
(\d{5}-\d{4}|\d{5})
```

Edit:

> However it doesn't retrieve only 12345 in case of a malformed Zip (eg. 12345-123)

Are you sure? This produces a match:

```
Dim zip5 As String = "12345"
Dim zip9 As String = "12345-6789"
Dim partialZip9 = "12345-33"
Dim regex As New Regex("(\d{5}-\d{4}|\d{5})")
Dim zip5Match = regex.Match(zip5).Groups(0).Value 'Produces 12345
Dim zip9Match = regex.Match(zip9).Groups(0).Value 'Produces 12345-6789
Dim partialZip9Match = regex.Match(partialZip9).Groups(0).Value 'Produces 12345
```

Comment: EDIT: It works. It doesn't work for a malformed Zip 12345-123 though. Is there any way to get just the first 5 digits in that case?

Comment: @Theveloper It seems to work for me on regexhero.net. Can you post the complete code using the regex, as well as sample inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: This works with just 12345! (sorry for the confusion) however, I didn't formulate the original question correctly. In case the zipcode is not formatted correctly 12345-12 or 12345-123, is there any way to match only 12345

Comment: @Theveloper Are you sure? I edited my answer with some code that seems to work.

Comment: You are correct, must be the text I have wrapped around it which is causing regex to perform incorrectly. Thank you!